# How to filter today's data from R dataframe?

Tags: r, lubridate

I want to subset data based on today's date. 
my data is having two columns : 1st column 'date' and 2nd column 'volume'.

```
mydf <- as.data.frame(c(2020-03-01,2020-03-02,2020-03-01),c(50,40,30))
```

Now, I would like to filter data with date matches with today's date i.e. 2020-03-02.

I tried with below code using library(lubridate):

```
mydf %>% filter(date == today())
```

Getting error:
'Error in today() : could not find function "today" '

Any help here is appreciable.

Comment: Works for me, did you load the package for sure?

Comment: `mydf %>% filter(date == lubridate::today())`

Comment: What is the output if you run `lubridate::today()`?

Comment: If you are entering the dates like that in a data frame, then they will be converted to numeric. 2020-03-01 = 2016. You need to quote the dates and surround them with `as.Date()`

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you for your helps.

Comment: Thank you for this help.